# Is it possible to create a virtual host on a virtual machine?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on a virtual box. My host PC is windows 7. 
I am developing a web application that is integrated with linux executable program. Since I don't have a linux server, if possible I would like to set a virtual host on my virtual machine to host my web app. Is it possible thing to do ? If yes, how to do it ? any tutorial for it (similar to this one https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/ for windows 7 but not a virtual machine) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i understood your query .yes, its possible to setup a guest os on your virtual machine go to this link  [complete ubuntu webserver tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKJ55ebMcOc) .hope this will help you!

Comment: I havent tried. because the ubuntu that i have is a desktop not server. And I cant install Ubuntu server on my virtualbox because there is no selection for 64 bit ubuntu server.

Comment: you can download server from [link]http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server  and ubuntu server  is  available only in 64 bit

Comment: yeah I know. my virtual box does not support Ubuntu 64 bit and I could not find virtualization on my bios menu

Comment: which version of virtual box you are using? even i installed server on virtual box of this version( VirtualBox 5.0.2 for Linux) its working fine

Comment: I am using version 4.3.25